# How can I undo the most recent file edit change in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to repeat this command multiple times to go back to the right point.
By doing this undo repeatedly, I might end up modifying many files overall, but one change in one file at a time.

The default ctrl-z undoes only within the current file that is open in the editor,
which often for me, is **NOT** the most recently edited file.

Is there anything **more granular than local history**, and without having to **remember which were the all the files I edited** and without having to **remember which is my most recent change, among multiple changes in each file**?

Answer (score 1):

You can always undo the changes you've made locally before you commit them: In the Commit tool window Alt+0 , select one or more files that you want to revert, and select Rollback from the context menu, or press Ctrl+Alt+Z.

But as you said you need more, maybe [this will help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/undo-changes.html#unstage-files)